create vectors of left- and right-most neighbours based on a ring network in R
I have a ring network in which agents should interact in a sequence based on their iterating left and right-most closest "neighborhood-partners".
I need to create a vector (i.e., their 'interaction sequence') for each agent i in, say, 1:100.
for i = 1, the vector should look like:
c(2,100,3,99,4,98, ...)
meaning i=1 is closest to 2, then 100, then 3, then 99 ...
for i = 2, the vector should look like:
c(1,3,100,4,99,...)
meaning i=2 is closest to 1, then 3, then 100, then 4 ...
for i = 50, the vector should look like:
c(49,51,48,52,47,...)
meaning i=50 is closest to 49, then 51, then 48, then 52 ...
[...]
for i = 100, the vector should look like:
c(99,1,98,2,97,...)
meaning i=100 is closest to 99, then 1, then 100, then 4 ...
Uneven agents (i.e., i %% 2 == 1) start with their right-most then left-most neighbours and so on.
Even agents (i.e., i %% 2 == 0) start with their left-most then right most neighbours and so on.
I struggle to and need help with finding an efficient algorithm that can generate the vector (or matrix of all vectors) for a given i, ideally avoiding loops.

for i=1. right (2) comes before left (100) but for i=2 left (1) comes before right (3). What is the logic?

this way, 1 is paired with 2, 3 with 4, 5 <-> 6, 7 <-> 8 etc. when only considering the first entry of each "interaction sequence vector"

A function to return the desired vectors as columns in a matrix:
f <- function(n) {
  n <- as.integer(n)
  n1 <- n - 1L
  if (n%%2) {
    v <- c(rbind(1:(n1/2), n1:((n + 1)/2)))
    m <- (outer(v, 0:n1, "+")%%n) + 1L
    m[,seq(2, n, 2)] <- c(matrix(m[,seq(2, n, 2)], 2)[2:1,])
  } else {
    v <- c(1L, c(rbind(n1:((n + 2)/2), 2:(n/2))))
    m <- (outer(v, 0:n1, "+")%%n) + 1L
    m[-n1, seq(2, n, 2)] <- c(matrix(m[-n1, seq(2, n, 2)], 2)[2:1,])
  }
  m
}

Demonstrating
f(10)
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    2    1    4    3    6    5    8    7   10     9
#>  [2,]   10    3    2    5    4    7    6    9    8     1
#>  [3,]    3   10    5    2    7    4    9    6    1     8
#>  [4,]    9    4    1    6    3    8    5   10    7     2
#>  [5,]    4    9    6    1    8    3   10    5    2     7
#>  [6,]    8    5   10    7    2    9    4    1    6     3
#>  [7,]    5    8    7   10    9    2    1    4    3     6
#>  [8,]    7    6    9    8    1   10    3    2    5     4
#>  [9,]    6    7    8    9   10    1    2    3    4     5
f(11)
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
#>  [1,]    2    1    4    3    6    5    8    7   10     9     1
#>  [2,]   11    3    2    5    4    7    6    9    8    11    10
#>  [3,]    3   11    5    2    7    4    9    6   11     8     2
#>  [4,]   10    4    1    6    3    8    5   10    7     1     9
#>  [5,]    4   10    6    1    8    3   10    5    1     7     3
#>  [6,]    9    5   11    7    2    9    4   11    6     2     8
#>  [7,]    5    9    7   11    9    2   11    4    2     6     4
#>  [8,]    8    6   10    8    1   10    3    1    5     3     7
#>  [9,]    6    8    8   10   10    1    1    3    3     5     5
#> [10,]    7    7    9    9   11   11    2    2    4     4     6

Benchmarking
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  f = f(100),
  fThomas = fThomas(100),
  check = "equal"
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>     expr    min      lq     mean median      uq     max neval
#>        f  199.9  219.75  241.655  231.5  244.85   593.6   100
#>  fThomas 1344.8 1546.50 1923.907 1644.3 1744.25 12203.6   100

fThomas from @ThomasIsCoding:
fThomas <- function(n) {
  v <- seq_len(n)
  sapply(
    v,
    \(i) {
      p <- ((v - 1 + i) %% n + 1)[1:(n - 1)]
      rbind(p, rev(p))[ifelse(i %% 2, rev, I)(2:1), ][1:(n - 1)]
    }
  )
}


nice solution without using any graph-related package, +1!

Here is a base R option
f <- function(n) {
    v <- seq_len(n)
    sapply(
        v,
        \(i) {
            p <- ((v - 1 + i) %% n + 1)[1:(n - 1)]
            ## or a bit shorter
            #p <- c(v[-(1:i)], v[1:i])[1:(n - 1)]
            rbind(p, rev(p))[ifelse(i %% 2, rev, I)(2:1), ][1:(n - 1)]
        }
    )
}

or a shorter version
f <- function(n) {
    apply(
        ((outer(1:n, 1:n, `+`) - 1) %% n + 1)[, -n],
        1,
        \(p) {
            rbind(p, rev(p))[ifelse(p[1] %% 2, I, rev)(2:1), ][1:(n - 1)]
        }
    )
}

such that
> f(10)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    2    1    4    3    6    5    8    7   10     9
 [2,]   10    3    2    5    4    7    6    9    8     1
 [3,]    3   10    5    2    7    4    9    6    1     8
 [4,]    9    4    1    6    3    8    5   10    7     2
 [5,]    4    9    6    1    8    3   10    5    2     7
 [6,]    8    5   10    7    2    9    4    1    6     3
 [7,]    5    8    7   10    9    2    1    4    3     6
 [8,]    7    6    9    8    1   10    3    2    5     4
 [9,]    6    7    8    9   10    1    2    3    4     5

> f(11)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
 [1,]    2    1    4    3    6    5    8    7   10     9     1
 [2,]   11    3    2    5    4    7    6    9    8    11    10
 [3,]    3   11    5    2    7    4    9    6   11     8     2
 [4,]   10    4    1    6    3    8    5   10    7     1     9
 [5,]    4   10    6    1    8    3   10    5    1     7     3
 [6,]    9    5   11    7    2    9    4   11    6     2     8
 [7,]    5    9    7   11    9    2   11    4    2     6     4
 [8,]    8    6   10    8    1   10    3    1    5     3     7
 [9,]    6    8    8   10   10    1    1    3    3     5     5
[10,]    7    7    9    9   11   11    2    2    4     4     6


Nicely parsimonious. I'll add it to my benchmark.

@jblood94 well, I don't think my code is as speedy as yours but just short like code-golfing

@jblood94 I made an shorter version in the update, but probably even slower
